# The set "T" mapped on all real numbers. Fairly "T" seems to be subset of set "S"

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f^{n}(x)$ exists for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where

\begin{aligned}
f^{n}(x)=f \circ f^{n-1}(x) \text { for } n & \geq 2 . \text { Define } \\
S &=\left\{\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f^{n}(x): x \in \mathbb{R}\right\} \text { and } T=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x)=x\}
\end{aligned}

Then which of the following is necessarily true?

A. $S \subset T$

B. $T \subset S$

$\mathrm{C} . S=T$

D. None of the above

Comment: This is a terrible, uninformative title.  Please fix it.

Comment: I agree with @DavidG.Stork. Try using a comprehensive title so that you get better and relevant answers! :)

Comment: yeah! i have changed.

Comment: Also, you have $f''$ when you presumably mean $f^n$.

Comment: thanks @TonyK. I have changeed now

Comment: I don't understand your approach at all. Can you try to explain it better?

Comment: @TonyK i have  attached image. Is it clear to u now?

Comment: Your equation $S=f(x)$ makes no sense. $S$ is a set of real numbers and $f(x)$ is a real number. Furthermore, given a particular function $f$, the value $f(x)$ is likely to be different for different values of $x$, whereas $S$ doesn't depend on the value of $x$.

Comment: so according to u T will be the subset of S?

Comment: It is _clearer_, at least. But $f(f(f(\ldots)))$ is meaningless. (Note that if $f$ is not continuous, then $S$ is not necessarily equal to $T$. So somewhere you have to use the continuity of $f$, which you have not done.)

Comment: i guess , for a competitive exam this much approach is sufficient to understand!

Comment: @RANCHO:  You're fairly new here, so here's some help with question:  Phrases such as "Am I going correctly?" should never be used.  Of *course* you're asking for help.  Such a phrase is useless chatter.  Also, "How do I know" is similarly useless and a waste of everyone's time.  And your title uses"$T$."  Ummm... what will readers think $T$ is?  Please read:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It is indeed very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but you have not done anything here that makes sense.

- You wrote out the definition of $f^2(x)$ and $f^3(x)$.
- You proclaimed "putting the value of $f(x) = x$" without any explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.
- Then you immediately jump to $S = \{f(x):x \in \Bbb R\}$, which does not at all follow from what you had written before.

Why?? What are you attempting to do with this?

For A) you have to show that every point of $S$ is also a point of $T$. That is, if $y$ is a real number for which $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^n(x) = y$ for some real number $x$, then $f(y) = y$. This would prove A true.
Either that, or else give an example of a continuous function $f$ for which $\lim_n f^n$ always converges, and a value $y \in S$ for which $y \ne f(y)$. This would prove A false.

For B) you have to show that if every point in $T$ is also a point of $S$. That is, if $f(y) = y$, then $y = \lim_{n\to \infty} f^n(x)$ for some $x$. This would prove B true. Either that or else give an example of such a function $f$ and a value $y$ such that $f(y) = y$, but $y \ne \lim_{n\to \infty} f^n(x)$ for any $x$. This would prove B false.

C is true if and only if both of A and B are true. So if you prove both A and B, you've also proven C. If you found a counter-example to A or to B, you've found a counter-example to C.

D is true if and only if both of A and B are false (since this implies C is false as well).

Comment: thanks! now it is clear to me! i am removing my approach.